# How to broadcast messages received from all the clients to all clients connected to the server in python?

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I am trying to write a chat server client program in python wherein the server recives messages from multiple clients and then the server broadcasts them to all the clients  connected to it. The program below sends the messages to the client but the broadcast code ain't working. Please help !!

Server.py
    import socket
    import sys
    import _thread

```
HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port
CONNECTION_LIST = []
MESSAGE_LIST = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ('Socket created')

#Bind socket to local host and port

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print ('Socket now listening')

def broadcast_data (cl, message):
 for sock in CONNECTION_LIST:
  for msg in MESSAGE_LIST:
   message = MESSAGE_LIST[0]+MESSAGE_LIST[1]
  conn.send(message.encode('ascii'))


#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn,addr):
    #Sending message to connected client
    #conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string

    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
 while True:

        #Receiving from client
  data = conn.recv(1024)
  data=data.decode('ascii')
  reply = 'Broadcasted message is'+data
  if not data: 
   break
  print("Message received from {0} is:".format(addr))
  print(data)
  MESSAGE_LIST.append(data)
  print(MESSAGE_LIST)
  break
 broadcast_data(CONNECTION_LIST, MESSAGE_LIST)

    #came out of loop



#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    CONNECTION_LIST.append(conn)

    print ('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))


    #from threading import Thread
    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    _thread.start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,addr))

s.close()
```

Client1.py

```
import socket

HOST =socket.gethostname()
PORT = 8888            
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

text=input('Enter your mesage:') #take message input from user
socket.send(text.encode('ascii'))     #send message to client

bmsg=socket.recv(1024)          #Recieve message from server
bmsg=bmsg.decode('ascii')

print('Message Received from server is:'+bmsg)
```

Client2.py

```
import socket

HOST =socket.gethostname()
PORT = 8888           
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

text=input('Enter your mesage:') #take message input from user
socket.send(text.encode('ascii'))     #send message to client

bmsg=socket.recv(1024)          #Recieve message from server
bmsg=bmsg.decode('ascii')

print('Message Received from server is:'+bmsg)
```